# Creating a shortcut to a program on thumb drive without drive letter

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, shortcuts, drive-letter

Is there a way to create a shortcut to an EXE on a USB thumb drive that will work no matter what drive letter is assigned to the thumb drive?

I have a program in a folder on a thumb drive.  I want to create a shortcut in the root of the thumb drive that points to the program's EXE and will work no matter what drive letter is assigned to the thumb drive.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I earlier versions of Windows you could leave off the drive letter to create a relative pathname. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be possible any more with Windows 10.

For example, if your executable is at:

> E:\folder\subfolder\program.exe

set the shortcut to be:

> \folder\subfolder\program.exe

or perhaps:

> folder\subfolder\program.exe

A bit of experimentation should reveal the correct format.

Comment: Relative is the way to go, +1.

Comment: I just came across this. Windows has never supported creating shortcuts with relative paths AFAIK (if you leave out the drive letter it will still be added), so I don't know why this is the accepted answer.

Comment: On Windows 10, you can NOT add a shortcut without drive letter. At least I'm not able to do that on my Win10 Pro b1909.

Comment: @PeterCo this answer was written 10 years ago. I can't remember what version of Windows was current then, but it certainly wasn't Windows 10 ;)

Answer (score 5):

We can also use batch files to achieve relative links.
Just put,

`start path/to/program.exe`

and put it in the root of the flash drive.. 
I am not sure if relative shortcuts(lnk files) can be used in windows...